# Tabs painted over "congrats" screen for new badge

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface

I've experienced a layout bug, see image:

[image]

The tabs are painted over the "congrats" dialog for a new badge.

When I click the button, the page gets repainted with sizes slightly changing, and it becomes:

[image]

which looks ok. Screenshots were taken without changing window dimensions (although I may not have been 100% exact with getting the same selection rectangle.)

I'm using Firefox 60.2.2esr on Devuan ASCII (~= Debian Stretch), on a x86_64 machine. If any additional information regarding my box is necessary, please ask for it.